# configure finds library, but ldd does not

Tags: autoconf, libtool, ldd

I am making use of a logging library, named *liblogger*, (that I've implemented) within another library, *libmsg*. For both of them, I'm using the autotools. I successfully install the liblogger library in my system, under the /usr/local/lib directory.

Within the configure.ac script of the other *libmsg*, I verify that liblogger is installed in the system, as follows:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([logger],
             [log_init],
             [],
             [
              echo "Error: Could not find liblogger."
              exit 1
             ])
```

And add the "-L/usr/local/lib" path to the LDFLAGS variable.

The AC_CHECK_LIB test finds the library, and both the *libmsg* library and its check_PROGRAMS using are successfully compiled.

However, when I try to execute the test programs, I get the error:

> error while loading shared libraries: liblogger.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Indeed, *ldd* does not find the library either:

```
$ ldd msgs
  linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff543ff000) 
  liblogger.so.0 => not found
  libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fdf329ad000)
```

But the library is actually there, in */usr/local/lib*.

For linking the test program, libtool is being called with the instruction:

```
$ /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -I../include -I../msg -L/usr/local/lib -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o msgs msgs.o message.o base64.o misc.o  -llogger  -lglib-2.0
```

Which actually echoes the following:

```
libtool: link: gcc -I../include -I../msg -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib -o msgs msgs.o message.o base64.o misc.o  -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/liblogger.so -lglib-2.0
```

So, the *-llogger* flag is being substituted by *-L[..] /usr/local/liblogger.so* (I suppose this is a correct behavior? I haven't been able yet to determine it...)

Actually, if I call the test program with:

> LDPRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/liblogger.so msgs

It actually works.

Can anyone tell me what is it what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if:

- `/usr/local/lib` is in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (it usually is these days).
- `ldconfig` was run when you installed `liblogger`.  If not, run it.
- `liblogger.so.0` is actually in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: `ldconfig` was not actually being run. It did solve the problem, thank you. Is there some way to make libtool execute it automatically?

Comment: `libtool` shouldn't execute `ldconfig`.  Even `make install` says to run `ldconfig` after, instead of running it itself.  Usually the package manager (RPM, apt, etc.) runs it since it really only needs to be run the first time the lib is installed (and after uninstallation).  Running `ldconfig` it also usually requires root privileges as well.